# EXC_BAD_ACCESS null exception in SKView's .texture(from) with non-nil node

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I'm getting an occasional `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` error when calling 'SKView.texture(from:)', which I understand (from the address 0x0) to be a null pointer dereference.

I'm calling it like this:

```
view.texture(from: node)
```

`view` is an `SKView` and `node` is an `SKNode`, neither is nil. This line gets called many many times for different nodes and works fine most of the time, but eventually (usually when there are a lot of nodes on the screen) I get a crash.

Stack trace from a typical crash:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000199b1da3c SpriteKit`-[SKTexture(Internal) initWithBackingTetxure:logicalWidth:height:] + 76
    frame #1: 0x0000000199baeff0 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::textureFromNode(SKCNode*, float, NSDictionary*) + 1052
    frame #2: 0x0000000199b2e428 SpriteKit`-[SKView textureFromNode:withOptions:] + 124
    frame #3: 0x0000000199b2e39c SpriteKit`-[SKView textureFromNode:] + 24
  * frame #4: 0x0000000104bf3534 Worf`SpriteComponent.texture(node=0x00000001c03113a0, self=0x00000001c0541e40) at SpriteComponent.swift:175
    ...
```

This is in Xcode 9.0 (9A235) using Swift 4 for iOS.

As Price Ringo points out, the trace makes it clear that the exception is occurring in `initWithBackingTetxure:logicalWidth:height`, a curiously spelled internal method of SKTexture.

What could be wrong with my `SKNode` that would cause this error, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score -1):

It is not that node or view are somehow nil but rather why does `initWithBackingTetxure:logicalWidth:height:`access 0. While it is possible there is a defect is the library, it is much more likely that the state of your node is bad.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that makes sense, but I'm having trouble understanding what could be wrong with the node. The documentation for `texture(from)` just says an `SKNode`, and it doesn't even have to be in the view's scene. Can you clarify what it means for the state of a node to be bad?